# How do I select a row in a listview not using ListActivity

Tags: android, listview

Here is the code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Find your views
    final ListView listPro = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listProperty);

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    db.open();

    final Cursor c = db.getAllProperties();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // Create the adapter
    MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(this, c);
    listPro.setAdapter(adapter);

    // here is where I think I should put the code to select the row but I 
            // haven't been able to figure out how to do it.
            // all I need to get out is the row id number.. please help

    Button addPropBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton);
    addPropBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i7 = new Intent(Main.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(i7);

        }

    });
}

}
```

Comment: What you ant to do with selected element?

Answer (score 2):

try this one, hope it will help you out.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    }
```

you can get the id number by using Log or System.out.println();

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Button's setOnClickListener use ListView's setOnItemClickListener.

```
listPro.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {


                }
            });
```

The id parameter will give you the needed id.

- Salil.

Comment: Salil you are amazing!!!! I have been searching for this for days. It was just that simple. Thank you!!!

Comment: @user712343 - Glad that I could help you. If this answer has helped then can you please mark it as the accepted answer.